# ListView сохранение позиции при повороте

Tags: listview, android-fragment, прокрутка

Здравствуйте, у меня есть активность Main. В ней по клику из Drawer'a я вызываю фрагмент в который что то загружаю из сети в ListView. Но если пролистать половину контента а затем повернуть устройство, то скролл возвращается в самое начало. Как этого избежать, подскажите? Была идея передать посдеднию позицию через аргументы фрагмента, но будет ли это верным решением?

Answer (score 0):

Во фрагменте:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    View v = adslist.getChildAt(0);
    int index = adslist.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    outState.putInt("index", index);
    outState.putInt("top", top);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        setScrollPosition(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public void setScrollPosition(Bundle scrollState) {

    if(scrollState != null) {
        top = scrollState.getInt("top", 0);
        index = scrollState.getInt("index", -1);
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```